# Optimal method for handling a changing array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, performance, fortran

Let's say I have an 2D array. Along the first axis I have a series of properties for one individual measurement. Along the second axis I have a series of measurements.

So, for example, the array could look something like this:

```
         personA personB personC
height   1.8     1.75    2.0
weight   60.5    82.0    91.3
age      23.1    65.8    48.5
```

or anything similar.

I want to change the size of the array very often - for example, ignoring `personB`'s data and including `personD` and `personE`. I will be looping through "time", probably with >10^5 timesteps. Each timestep, there is a chance that each "person" in the array could be deleted and a chance that they will introduce several new people into the simulation.

From what I can see there are several ways to manage an array like this:

### Overwriting and infrequent reallocation

I could use a very large array with an extra column, in which I put a "skip" flag. So, if I decide I no longer need `personB`, I set the flag to `1` and ignore `personB` every time I loop through the list of people. When I need to add `personD`, I search through the list for the first person with `skip == 1`, replace the data with the data for `personD`, and set `skip = 0`. If there aren't any people with `skip == 1`, I copy the array, deallocate it, reallocate it with several more columns, and then fill the first new column with `personD`'s data.

Advantages:

- infrequent allocation - possibly better performance
- easy access to array elements
- easier to optimise

Disadvantages:

- if my array shrinks a lot, I'll be wasting a lot of memory
- I need a whole extra row in the data, and I have to perform checks to make sure I don't use the irrelevant data. If the array shrinks from 1000 people to 1, I'm going to have to loop through 999 extra records
- could encounter memory issues, if I have a very large array to copy

### Frequent reallocation

Every time I want to add or remove some data, I copy and reallocate the entire array.

Advantages:

- I know every piece of data in the array is relevant, so I don't have to check them
- easy access to array elements
- no wasted memory
- easier to optimise

Disadvantages:

- probably slow
- could encounter memory issues, if I have a very large array to copy

### A linked list

I refactor everything so that each individual's data includes a pointer to the next individual's data. Then, when I need to delete an individual I simply remove it from the pointer chain and deallocate it, and when I need to add an individual I just add some pointers to the end of the chain.

Advantages:

- every record in the chain is relevant, so I don't have to do any checks
- no wasted memory
- less likely to encounter memory problems, as I don't have to copy the entire array at once

Disadvantages:

- no easy access to array elements. I can't slice with `data(height,:)`, for example
- more difficult to optimise

I'm not sure how this option will perform compared to the other two.

--

So, to the questions: are there other options? When should I use each of these options? Is one of these options better than all of the others in my case?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm tempted to vote for closing on the basis of "too broad".  Essentially, perhaps you're best placed to determine the correct answer by profiling each of the cases against your own use.  [That is, I suspect the answer to your final question is "no" - which makes the second somewhat less precise to answer.]

Comment: Here's another option: use a work-array of a certain size, and keep track of how many entries you add. Once the array is full, re-allocate it to a larger size. You could use a fixed increment (e.g. 1000), or double the array in size. This should give you a good compromise between flexibility and speed. Beyond that, I agree with @francescalus in that the question is pretty broad.

Comment: Perhaps the question is too broad, but I had hoped people would be able to give me some general comments as to when option 1 is faster than option 2, for example. I don't know what the overheads for allocation and copying are like in Fortran. If they're massive, option 1 is clearly superior - if they're tiny, option 2 is far simpler, so probably the better option. The linked list approach is quite different, so I suppose it's harder to make a comparison with that, and it'll depend heavily on the use case.

Comment: Yet another option.  It would be similar to "overwriting and infrequent reallocation."  Except you could use an integer variable to keep track of how many list entries are flagged for "skip."  If this counter becomes too large compared to the size of the array, then you could reallocate and copy to a new array with *fewer* columns to avoid wasting memory.

Comment: *I don't know what the overheads for allocation and copying are like in Fortran*  They're not really determined by features of Fortran, but of implementations on particular systems.  They're probably similar, on one platform, to measurements of similar operations coded in other, if not most, imperative programming languages.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - ah, now I see why the question isn't particularly useful. I suppose the best thing to do would be to write a few versions of my program and see which performs best then. _Premature optimisation is the root of all evil_, so they say, but I find I save myself a lot of time if I get the structure of the program right from the start - that's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: *I find I save myself a lot of time if I get the structure of the program right from the start* or, like many of us, you commit mentally to an approach you become reluctant to test rigorously against other options.  It's just so much work !  But I concur with your conclusion, and @francescalus's advice above, that running some tests is a good way to answer your (sort of) question.